# java rest web service RuntimeException WEB9033

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-ee

i'm developing a rest web service in java.

i'm using htmlparser library on it.

but when i try to run service i'm getting this exception. i can build it successfully. and org.htmlparser.beans.StringBean class exists in project.

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: WEB9033: Unable to load class with name [org.htmlparser.beans.StringBean], reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/htmlparser/visitors/NodeVisitor

root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: WEB9033: Unable to load class with name [org.htmlparser.beans.StringBean], reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/htmlparser/visitors/NodeVisitor

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/htmlparser/visitors/NodeVisitor

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.htmlparser.visitors.NodeVisitor
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that `WEB-INF/lib/htmlparser.jar` exists in the server.

Comment: htmlparser.jar and other jar files exist there.